# Expecting JSON object instead of JSON Array

Tags: json, django, rest

In my django application with database engine djongo, I'm trying to return a JSON response by retrieving from my database. But, I'm receiving JSON array instead of JSON object. Currently, there is only one record in my database. Please see the code below.

model.py

```
class bloodDonors(models.Model):
location=models.CharField(max_length=20)
name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
phone=models.IntegerField()
address=models.TextField()
bloodGroup=models.CharField(max_length=5)
type=models.CharField(max_length=20)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

views.py

```
class bloodDonersView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = bloodDonors.objects.all()
    serializer_class = bloodDonorsSerializer
```

JSON Reponse:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "location": "Delhi",
        "name": "Tony",
        "phone": 888,
        "address": "South street",
        "bloodGroup": "B+",
        "type": "blood-donation"
    }
]
```

But, actually I needed the response as given below:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "location": "Delhi",
    "name": "Tony",
    "phone": 888,
    "address": "South street",
    "bloodGroup": "B+",
    "type": "blood-donation"
}
```

Comment: Sending an outer list is not a good idea: https://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/

Comment: the `.all()` query will always return you an array or "Query Set" as djongo calls it because your DB could have multiple records. 

So you need to iterate your array or explicitly pull out the JSON object in that array. 

When you get your JSON Array, iterate through it (for loop or while loop or iterator)

Comment: using iterator how to send the data over JSON response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the 'list' endpoint that retrieves all objects matching the queryset, but you want to be using the detail `retrieve` endpoint, where you just retrieve one object. The good news is that because you are using a Model viewset, you get a detail `retrieve` `GET` endpoint for free. All you have to do is pass in the `pk` of the object you want as part of the url and it will return only the single object you requested.

So if your url is currently:

```
/api/v1/blood-donors
```

you'd want to use the url:

```
/api/v1/blood-donors/3
```

to get just the single object you want (with `pk=3`).  The `GET` endpoint with no `/{PK}` at the end is always going to return a list, even if there's only one object in your database, and if you add the `pk` to the url you will always only get one object back, the object that matches the `pk` you pass in.

Update to answer your question in the comment. The new method would look something like this:

```
class bloodDonersView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = bloodDonors.objects.all()
    serializer_class = bloodDonorsSerializer

    @action(detail=False, methods=['get',], url_path='first')
    def get_first_object(self, request):
        object = bloodDonors.objects.first()
        serializer = bloodDonorsSerializer(object, many=False)
        return response.Response(serializer.data)
```

the url you would use is

```
api/v1/blood-donors/first
```

and you need to check the documentation about where to import response and the action decorator.

Comment: without using pk, can we do this? considering that there is only one object in whole the database.

Comment: Not with a list API endpoint. You can write a custom endpoint that just returns a single object by invoking your serializer with a `many=False` kwarg. You basically have to decorate it with an `@action` decorator, set detail to False (meaning it won't require a pk) and make return just a single object passed to your serializer with `many=False`.

Comment: can you please a little elaborate on this technique? I cannot relate any articles on this.

Comment: It's difficult to elaborate in a comment due to character and formatting constraints. This is an odd thing to need, if there is only one object in the db, wouldn't you know the pk? And what happens if there is more than one object in the db - will you only ever have one blood donor? What should the behavior be if there's more than one? Should you just take the first object? Or the last? I don't quite understand what you're going for here, but I will update my answer to give you the endpoint you want selecting the first item in the db (which will be the one you want bc it's the only one).

Comment: If this is helpful to you, could you please accept my answer? (I updated to show you how to do what I was suggesting you do)